# .htaccess rewrites my urls when I don't want it to!

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get .htaccess to rewrite urls for my site. For example:

```
/Lessons/PhrasalVerbs/PVList/bringup
```

becomes

```
/index.php?page=Lessons/PhrasalVerbs/PVList/bringup
```

This seems to be a relatively common desire, so after looking around the internet, I came up with (read copied bemusedly) this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now as is, things work, but it's the second, not the first url, that appears in the bar. Now if I change the last line from

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now the address bar looks fine, but the site goes from looking correct to losing most of its formatting and images... (unfortuntely I can't post images, or links to images...)

Also, if I click on, for example, the link to the "bring up" page again, the url goes from

```
/Lessons/PhrasalVerbs/PVList/bringup
```

to

```
/Lessons/PhrasalVerbs/PVList/Lessons/PhrasalVerbs/PVList/bringup
```

So it's sort of repeating itself.

As is probably clear, I'm completely useless at mod_rewrite and am very confused. As this seems to be a fairly common use of .htaccess, I'm hoping someone can point out my stupid mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common mistake when doing URL rewriting and it has nothing to do with mod_rewrite.

The problem is that you’re using relative URLs in your documents. And relative URLs are resolved by the client using a base URL that is the document’s URL is not specified otherwise.

So if the document’s URL path is `/foo/bar` and there is a link in it with the relative URL `baz/quux`, the client resolves it to `/foo/baz/quux` as `baz/quux` is resolved relatively to `/foo/bar` and not to `/`.

You can fix this by using absolute paths instead, i.e. `/baz/quux` instead of `baz/quux`. Or by explicitly changing the base URI using the [`BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE). But I wouldn’t do that as it affects *all* relative URLs and not just relative URL paths.

Comment: Hey thanks! that helped clear things up considerably. I went ahead and used the base element, which worked. I don't fully understand what you mean by the sentence "But I wouldn’t do that as it affects all relative URLs and not just relative URL paths." But knowing programming, it will probably come back to bite me in the behind. Now the site works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Michael Beeson: I meant that the new base URL would also apply for URLs like `?foo` (query only) or `#foo` (fragment only).